# One vs Two Objects Of Related Information

Tags: php, oop

When having two related objects, is it best to have them as one object or two separate?

For example, if you have an Artist object and an array of Album objects that relate to a single Artist.

```
<?php 
// two separate objects?
$artist = $ArtistDataMapper->find(1);
$album = $AlbumDataMapper->allByArtist($artist->id);
// or one
$artist = $AristDataMapper->find(1);  //datamapper will also include query for albums
```

Comment: This depends entirely on your requirements. Thinking of programming as "how do I best store my data" is just one way to program. Another way to program is "how do I best manipulate the data".

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your purpose is.
However, if you think about it as physical entities you might end up thinking of "references" to different entities.
By this I mean that, you might have:
 * Artist  object (id, name, birth date, etc.)
 * Album object (id, artistId, name, etc.)

Eventually, you might want to have even Discography objects between the two.

It's up to you and your requirements, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Classes and objects are abstractions. When defining them the program designer tries to separate separate parts of the code into logical entities that make sense in that respective context. The key concepts when doing OOP (Object Oriented design are `abstraction`, `encapsulation` and `inheritance`, which I recommend you to study. Other side topics to study are [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)), [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle), [GRASP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_(object-oriented_design)) principles. Maybe some of them are complex, but some are quite simple. For example `S` from SOLID stands for *single responsibility*. This principle suggests that one class should have only one purpose and define only one type of objects. In your case, the artists are a different logical entity than an album. An artist *produces* albums, which denotes that there is a relationship between these to, but they are not identical. An artist can do other things besides albums, like concerts or interviews, and an album can be produced also by groups of artists or by other entities, and in general have different attributes than an artist.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I will read into some of your suggestions.